# objective c operator meaning

Tags: objective-c

what is the meaning of << and & in objective?
for example ((touchedPads & (1 << 0)) != 0)

Answer (score 3):

Those are left bit shift and bitwise & respectively, and they are not objective-c specific. They are both C operators